# fullpage js how to dynamically update scrolloverflow bar

Tags: angular, fullpage.js

Hi i'm currently using a fullpageJS port in my angular 2 project and on one of the pages i have set to true,

```
 @Input() public options: MnFullpageOptions = new MnFullpageOptions({
scrollOverflow: true,
```

However, the content on my page can change, but currently the scrollbar does not update to fit all of the content (as I load more data at the bottom when a user clicks load). It will only update the scrollbar when the page is resized. How can I trigger a re-render of the scrollbaroverflow bar so that it will update to the content of my page?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `reBuild` function of fullPagejs. Check the docs for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up figuring that out